# How to show infoWindow for Circle on Google Maps in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to display circles at specific locations on google maps whose radius will be defined at runtime depending on some value.

I could add the circle on map using :

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
         .center(result)
         .radius(Double.parseDouble(size)*100)
         .strokeColor(Color.RED)
         .fillColor(Color.BLUE)
         );
```

When i click on this circle, i need to display an `infoWindow` same as the one that appears in case of `Markers` (i.e setting `titles and snippets` for each one of them and displaying on clicking it).

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Marker with 0x0 px icon at the same position as Circle.

When user clicks close enough to the center, info window will show for you.

You still have to handle case when user clicks far from the center using OnMapClickListener and calling marker.showInfoWindow().

Comment: We can also do with setting the alpha for existing marker equal to 0.0F, which will make the existing marker fully transparent as per the alpha value, and  will also show infowindow for the fully transparent marker